# How can I explode the following parameters into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following parameters for example:

```
max_image_width=100,max_image_height=200,image_proportion=1.75
```

I want to get an array with:

```
array('max_image_width'=>100,'max_image_height'=>200,'image_proportion'=175);
```

Comment: one way: explode on comma first,loop through the array exploding on equals (=)

Comment: Have you tried anything, or were you just hoping for someone to write up a complete solution?

Comment: Where are you getting `max_image_width=100,max_image_height=200,image_proportion=1.75`? is that a string or...?

Comment: Since you used the word "explode" instead of "split", I assume you're already aware of the explode function, so what more do you want?

Comment: i'm getting the parameters from the database. i wanted a solution using minimum number of lines like the one using parse_ini_string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = 'max_image_width=100,max_image_height=200,image_proportion=1.75';
$cfg = parse_ini_string(
    str_replace(',', "\n", $str)
);

print_r($cfg);
```

Answer (score 3):

5.4

```
$a=[];foreach(explode(',',$i)as$b){$a[explode('=',$b)[0]]=explode('=',$b)[1];}
```

Comment: Is there a reason it's on one line?

Comment: Its a stupid question. He should get a semi-confusing answer.

Comment: Ah, +1 for that comment.

Comment: +1 I see what you did here. Chapeau!

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = array();
parse_str(str_replace(',', '&', 'max_image_width=100,max_image_height=200,image_proportion=1.75'), $output);
```

Answer (score 2):

E.g. by using [preg_match_all](http://docs.php.net/preg_match_all).

```
<?php
$t = 'max_image_width=100,max_image_height=200,image_proportion=1.75';

preg_match_all('!([^=]+)=([^,]+)!', $t, $m);
$x = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);

var_export($x);
```

prints

```
array (
  'max_image_width' => '100',
  ',max_image_height' => '200',
  ',image_proportion' => '1.75',
)
```

( though there are tons of other ways to do it without regular expressions ;-) )